# What determines the frequency (and type) of acquiring special items?

Tags: pokemon-go

The special items that were added with the gen 2 Pokemon are really hard to get.

I have hit hundreds of Pokestops and have only gotten a total of 3 special items, and a max of 2 at a time. I used the metal coat and then a few days later I got metal coat again. I also have 1 dragon scale. My husband has gotten only 2 special items and they were different from mine so it's not location specific as to which items you can get.

Has anyone looked at the code surrounding special items?

Has anyone had more than two at a time in their inventory?

Answer (score 2):

I had 5 before using two of them earlier today (2 Sun Stones, 1 King's Rock, 2 Metal Coats). Unless your inventory is full, it's safe to assume there's no limit to how many evolution items you can have.

They are, however, very rare. [Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/gen-2-pokestop-item-drops-berries-evolution-items-changed/) have done some extensive research and found a drop rate of roughly 0.03% on average for each of the evolution items, for a total of 0.14% for any given item being an evolution item. Assuming 3-4 items per PokeStop spin on average, this translates to roughly 1 evolution item in 200 PokeStops on average. Their sample size is over 23'000 items, so somewhere around 7000 PokeStop spins.

During the first few days after they were released, the drop rate for evolution items on a 7 day streak was extremely high, nearly guaranteeing one, but this has since been changed.

Comment: Damn. That's really infrequent.

Comment: On logging in today I got a message saying the 7-day streak "first poke stop of the day" guarantees an evolution item, (although that has not been the case for me since the first few days, as scenia says) so it looks like they've changed it back.

Comment: I got that one, too. I'm hoping it means they did change it back. We'll see when the next few reports of 7-day streaks come in.